# How do I get rid of extra keyboard layouts in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10

As shown here, I only have 2 languages selected, with one keyboard each:

[image]

[image]

But in my keyboard menu, I have 4:

[image]

How can I get rid of English (US) and French (Legacy) Canadian?

Answer (score 0):

Select the language, then click Options

[image]

On the keyboard section, select the keyboard you want to get rid off, then click Remove.

[image]

Comment: I only have one keyboard shown in that menu. To get rid of it I have to add the keyboard and then remove it. But then it returns every time I restart the computer. How can I make it go away permanently